# JavaFX8 Human vs AI game play. Allowing delay for human action

Tags: delay, javafx-8

I am writing Checkers game that, as the title suggests, is between a human player and AI. Each checker for a human player has set drag detection. OnDragDetected collects coordinates of the checker's current location. OnDragDropped collects coordinates of where a player wants to drop the checker. Once this action is completed there is a bunch of other functions happening to ensure that the move is valid. If the move is valid then it's AI's turn. After AI does its move it's human player's turn and so on.

The problem I am having is that I have to somehow delay all the functions that happen after the player drags and drops the checker as I need to collect information about the coordinates first.

I've tried numerous things but with no success. I would really appreciate any pointers as this is my first program in which I use JavaFX.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be invoking the validation checks on the player's move in an event handler that captures the player move. Maybe have a look at my [Tic Tac Toe (Noughts and Crosses) implementation](https://github.com/james-d/TicTacToe) as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure I know what you mean by "delay" here. You just need to manage everything with event handlers, and keep track of where the piece is moved from and moved to. Then check validity when the user tries to complete the move (typically by releasing the drag).

Here's a very basic outline (one player just moving pieces). In real life of course the square state (`occupied`) would be more complex (two players, etc), as would the move validation. But it should give you an idea.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CheckersExample extends Application {

    private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 10 ;

    private static final int SQUARE_SIZE = 60 ;
    private static final int PIECE_RADIUS = 25 ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Use a GridPane for the board:
        GridPane board = new GridPane();

        // track where move is made from and to
        ObjectProperty<Square> moveFrom = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        ObjectProperty<Square> moveTo = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        // Create the squares and add views of them to the grid pane:
        for (int y=0; y<BOARD_SIZE; y++) {
            for (int x=0; x<BOARD_SIZE; x++) {
                Square square = new Square(x, y);
                board.add(square.getView(), x, y);

                // alternate squares in last 3 rows are occupied:

                if (y >= BOARD_SIZE-3 && (x + y) % 2 == 1) {
                    square.setOccupied(true);
                }

                // add event handlers for dragging to enable moving pieces:

                setUpDraggingForMove(square, moveFrom, moveTo);
            }
        }

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(board);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("checkers.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void setUpDraggingForMove(Square square, ObjectProperty<Square> moveFrom,
            ObjectProperty<Square> moveTo) {

        // CSS pseudoclass for highlighting squares before moving to them:
        PseudoClass highlight = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("highlight");

        // when starting drag, if square has a piece, set the moveFrom:

        square.getView().setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            if (square.isOccupied()) {
                moveFrom.set(square) ;

                // this enables drag events to other nodes (squares):
                square.getView().startFullDrag();
            }
        });

        // if dragging onto a square that's a valid move, highlight it and set the moveTo:

        square.getView().setOnMouseDragEntered(event -> {
            if (moveValid(moveFrom.get(), square)) {
                square.getView().pseudoClassStateChanged(highlight, true);
                moveTo.set(square);
            }
        });

        // when dragging off a square, un-highlight it and unset the moveTo:

        square.getView().setOnMouseDragExited(event -> {
            square.getView().pseudoClassStateChanged(highlight, false);
            moveTo.set(null);
        });

        // when releasing, if the move is valid, set the moveFrom to be unoccupied and the 
        // moveTo to be occupied:

        square.getView().setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
            if (moveValid(moveFrom.get(), moveTo.get())) {
                moveFrom.get().setOccupied(false);
                moveTo.get().setOccupied(true);
            }
            moveFrom.set(null);
            moveTo.set(null);
        });
    }

    // check validity of move:

    private boolean moveValid(Square from, Square to) {
        if (from == null ||                          // no from
            to   == null ||                          // no to
            !from.isOccupied() ||                    // from occupied
            to.isOccupied() ||                       // to occupied
            from.getY() - to.getY() != 1 ||          // not moving forward
            Math.abs(from.getX() - to.getX()) != 1)  // not moving sideways
        {
            return false ;
        } else {
            return true ;
        }

    }


    // represents a square on the board. Encapsulates its position (x and y),
    // whether or not it contains a piece (occupied)
    // and exposes a UI component representing it (view):

    private static class Square {
        private final int x ;
        private final int y ;
        private final BooleanProperty occupied ;

        private final StackPane view ;

        public Square(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x ;
            this.y = y ;
            this.occupied = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "occupied", false);

            this.view = createView();
        }

        private StackPane createView() {

            // use a StackPane as the base view:

            StackPane view = new StackPane();
            view.getStyleClass().add("square");

            // pseudoclass to enable alternate color on alternate squares:

            PseudoClass oddClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("odd");

            // fill GridPane cell:

            GridPane.setFillHeight(view, true);
            GridPane.setFillWidth(view, true);

            // fix size:

            view.setMinSize(SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE);
            view.setMaxSize(SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE);

            // set pseudoclass state for "odd" squares:

            if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
                view.pseudoClassStateChanged(oddClass, true);
            } 

            // add piece to stack pane...

            Circle piece = new Circle(SQUARE_SIZE/2, SQUARE_SIZE/2, PIECE_RADIUS);
            piece.getStyleClass().add("piece");
            view.getChildren().add(piece);

            // .. but only actually display it if the square is occupied:

            piece.visibleProperty().bind(occupied);

            return view ;
        }

        public Node getView() {
            return view ;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x ;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y ;
        }

        public final BooleanProperty occupiedProperty() {
            return this.occupied;
        }

        public final boolean isOccupied() {
            return this.occupiedProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setOccupied(final boolean occupied) {
            this.occupiedProperty().set(occupied);
        }       

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

checkers.css:

```
.root {

    /* and.. breathe... */

    -fx-padding: 40px ;
}

.square {

    /* use a looked-up color for the main background of a square, 
       so it's easy to change */

    -square-background: antiquewhite ;

    /* nest some backgrounds to give the effect of a raised border: */
    -fx-background-color: white, lightgray, darkgray, black, -square-background ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0px, 1px 1px 0px 0px, 2px 2px 1px 1px, 4px 4px 2px 2px, 5px 5px 3px 3px ;
}
.square:odd {
    /* change the main background on "odd" squares: */
    -square-background: cornflowerblue ;
}

.square:highlight {
    /* and change it again for highlighted squares: */
    -square-background: lightgoldenrodyellow ;
 }

.piece {
    /* color for pieces: */
    -fx-fill: steelblue ;
}
```